# How to use com.android.support.AppCompatActivity when using com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha3?

Tags: android, user-interface

`com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha3` requires a minimum sdk version of 28 and `com.android.support.AppCompatActivity` uses 27. So there is an error when I try and run the program.

Also, in the official material design docs, it is stated that `com.android.material` and `com.android.support` should not be used together.

So, when I remove `com.android.support.AppCompatActivity`, the compiler fails to resolve `AppCompatActivity`. What should I do?

*UPDATE*
I was able to resolve the exception by removing com.google.android. There was an error because com.google.android cannot be used with com.android.support.

But I get this error now:
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl714979868.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #7): Requires development platform P but this is a release platform.]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 'P'
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
api 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'

//implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'

androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use alpha version of AppCompat library also.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

Comment: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'

Comment: This is what happens

Comment: @BarathR Share gradle file

Comment: I have shared the gradle and an update on my current issue

Comment: @BarathR You should check compileSdkVersion = 28. insteadof P